# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

Tags: android, firebase

Estou tentando pegar lat e lang que está salvo no firebase e recuperar no mapa, mPost_key é o `uid` do usuário , este código funciona, mais da esse erro quando boto o mPost_key , usso este mesmo método `mDatabase.child(mPost_key)` na atividade pra trazer outras informações do usuário e também funciona

> Citação
>   03-06 19:53:11.270 29642-29642/com.robertoc.meublogclash E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.robertoc.meublogclash.User
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.robertoc.meublogclash.Perfil$1.onChildAdded(Perfil.java:128)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbox.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>   03-06 19:53:11.503 29642-29642/com.robertoc.meublogclash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.robertoc.meublogclash, PID: 29642
>                                                                              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.robertoc.meublogclash.User
>                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                  at com.robertoc.meublogclash.Perfil$1.onChildAdded(Perfil.java:128)
>                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbox.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>   03-06 19:53:11.562 1270-1399/? E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

     mPost_key = getIntent().getExtras().getString("uidusuario");

     mDatabase.child(mPost_key).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                User childUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                LatLng childPos = new LatLng(childUser.getLat(), childUser.getLang());
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(childPos);
                Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                userMarkers.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), marker);
                userMap.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), childUser);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Minha Clase USer

public class User {

```
private double lat;
private double lang;

public User(){}




public double getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(double lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public double getLang() {
    return lang;
}

public void setLang(double lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não entendo o porque de sem o `mPost_key` o código trabalha corretamente, no caso `mPost_key` é para quando entrar no perfil trazer somente a posição no mapa do uid do `mPost_key` ou seja um usuario só.

**RESOLVIDO**O erro era no banco de dados tinha um numero no meio do caminho perdido causando o erro.

Comment: O próprio ERRO já te dá uma pista, "Can't convert object of type java.lang.String"... você está tentando converter um objeto em uma string. Qual linha está dando erro?

Comment: A linha onde você declara `mPost_key` me parece que te retorna uma `string` e o código espera `User`. Alguma pista?

Comment: User childUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class); essa é a linha a Linha do erro

Comment: `mPost_key` trás  o uid do usuário do fire base

Comment: não sei oque estava acontecendo mais estava fazendo do jeito certo, refiz e funcionou.. obrigado quem respondeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro exibido:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object
>   of type java.lang.String to type com.robertoc.meublogclash.User at

Quer dizer que ele não consegue converter em `java.lang.String` um `com.robertoc.meublogclash.User`:

Tente mudar esta linha:

```
User childUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

Para :

```
User childUser = dataSnapshot.getValue("ValorUsuario");
```

Sendo, `ValorUsuario` o nome da propriedade!

**EDIT**

Conforme a documentação, não e necessário informar um parâmetro:

```
  User childUser = dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

> getValue() Retorna os dados contidos neste snapshot como tipos nativos. 
>   Os tipos possíveis retornados são:
>
> - Boolean
> - String
> - Long
> - Double
> - Map
> - List
>
> Esta lista é recursiva; Os tipos possíveis para Object na lista acima são  dados pela mesma lista. Estes tipos correspondem aos tipos disponíveis no  JSON.

[Segue a documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot)

Comment: como faço pra colocar ValorUsuario = nome da propriedade?

Comment: estas propriedades estão alinhas em um objeto certo? é esta propriedade que é o **valorUsuario**

Comment: Se deixar sem nenhum parâmetro dentro de `getValue()` da erro.